# Rest Method: Returns Collection of XML instead of proper grouping

Tags: java, rest

I have the following POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String profession;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String profession) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
```

And the service is defined as:

```
@GET 
@Path("/users") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
List<User> getUsers();
```

When I make a call out using a REST client (Java or Postman), I get the following XML back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collection>
    <User>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Mahesh</name>
        <profession>Teacher</profession>
    </User>
</collection>
```

Why is the returning XML containing `<collection>` instead of `<Users>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `List<User>` into separate object and use `@XMLElementWrapper` on that collection.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html

I didn't test that but you can try to use `@XMLElementWrapper` on `getUsers()`

Comment: I tried adding the `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Users")` in the service on `getUsers()` but it did not do anything. I am not sure I can wrap the `List<User>` into another Object as that is a requirement for the service.

Comment: But you are exporting XML, so how you achieve that is not a concern of consumer.

Comment: Because in the client, I need to also be able to pass in a `GenericType<List<User>>()` as well

Comment: Such as: `List<User> users = client.target(endpoint)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .get(new GenericType<List<User>>() {});`

Comment: You will probably need generic root element as well for that.